# Subtract a list of strings from another list of strings C# and keep the duplicates

Tags: c#, list

Lets say I have two lists.

`Firstlist = {1,2,2,2,3}`
`Secondlist = {1,2,2,3}`
`Firstlist - Secondlist = {2}`

I have tried converting them to integers and summing them and basically `(Firstlist.Sum() - Secondlist.Sum())`, but the sums get too big for an integer value.

Tried `Firstlist.Except(Secondlist)`, but it disposes of duplicates.

For/for each loops take too much time.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: *too much time* - slow to run or slow to code?

Comment: Too slow to run, since the lists can contain a huge amount of strings

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Getting the difference of the sums of the lists or getting the *intersection* of the lists?

Comment: ‘Foreach’ with dictionary should be O(len_first + len_second)... I don’t think you can get better than that. Please show your code

Comment: So they're lists of strings now? (Your question used ints and said you summed them)

Comment: No, the title says that its a list of strings and I have mentioned that I'm converting them to ints

Comment: OK.. `Firstlist = {1,2,2,2,3}` looked like a list of ints to me, but it's not so important - bear in mind that I wrote my answer as if they were ints (the second code block would need to be `var d = new Dictionary<string, int>();` if you use strings

Comment: Are the input lists sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about we turn the second list into a dictionary of unique keys and the number of times they appeared, then skip over the first list removing anything if the dictionary "can pay for it":

```
var d = Secondlist.GroupBy(i => i).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
for(int i = Firstlist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if(d.TryGetValue(Firstlist[i], out int ctr) && ctr > 0){
    d[Firstlist[i]]--;
    Firstlist.RemoveAt(i);
  }
```

Tbh I think rather than LINQ I'd build the dictionary myself too:

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var x in Secondlist)
  if(!d.ContainsKey(x))
    d[x] = 1;
  else 
    d[x]++;
```

If performance still sucks, you might need to so something about the RemoveAt; it'll do a lot of shuffling. Perhaps consider (if order is unimportant) copying the last entry in the list over the top of the one you want to erase, and shorten the list by one.. Or use a different container that's faster for removes (linked list for example)

Comment: Ok, so dictionary was the way. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are looking for some kind of *Linq* solution, you can `GroupBy`:

```
  var Firstlist = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 9 };
  var Secondlist = new List<int> { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };

  Dictionary<int, int> remove = Secondlist
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

  var result = Firstlist
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .Select(group => group.Take(group.Count() - 
       (remove.TryGetValue(group.Key, out var count) ? count : 0)))
    .SelectMany(group => group)
    .ToList();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome:

```
  2, 4, 4, 4, 9
```